# Как достать св-во из объекта

Tags: javascript

Есть объект ranges в качестве св-ва  принимает объект {…}

```
 ranges: {b919b19c-0205-11ea-a217-5404a6b707f3: {…}}
```

Как мне достать свойство ключа b919b19c-0205-11ea-a217-5404a6b707f3, которое является тоже объектом

Вот в консоли 
ranges:

```
b919b19c-0205-11ea-a217-5404a6b707f3:
dt: -5
latitude: 55.96469809124985
length: 10
longitude: 38.06365136591642
```

Нужно некое уневерсальное решение если в ответе от сервера не ['b9....'] . а другое значение (при той же структуре)., как получать свойство?

Comment: `ranges['b9....']` так, или что?

Comment: а если в ответе от сервера не ['b9....']  . а другое значение (при той же структуре) как получать свойство? Нужно некое уневерсальное решение

Comment: @Help-myFather, Вы получаете объект и не знаете имя свойства? `Object.keys(ranges)`

Answer (score 1):

```
ranges[Object.keys(ranges)[0]]
```

Comment: а если порядок не строгий, или может быть изменен в будущем? хотя такой формат не пойдет тогда.

Comment: Решение не универсальное. А если искомый ключ будет zb919b19c-0205-11ea-a217-5404a6b707f3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Если известны остальные ключи и они фиксированы(dt, latitude,length, longtitude), я бы перебрал `Object.keys(ranges)` и если ключ неизвестен - считал бы его тем что нужно(или придумать ещё какой-то критерий, но тут надо знать больше специфику ranges). Например:

```
const keysFilter = ['dt', 'latitude', 'length', 'longitude']; 

const ranges = {'b919b19c-0205-11ea-a217-5404a6b707f3': 'test',
   dt: 5,
   latitude: 55.96469809124985,
   length: 10,
   longitude: 38.06365136591642
};

console.log(Object.keys(ranges).filter(key => !keysFilter.includes(key)));
```